# What is the difference between the npm modules jsonwebtoken and jwt-simple?

Tags: jwt, json-web-token

One example suggested using 'jsonwebtoken' and another suggested 'jwt-simple'... what are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jwt-simple is smaller than jsonwebtoken, just `encode` and `decode`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the technical difference but for anything security related, I would go with the more active, more popular choice, and looking at the github statistics that choice seems to be jsonwebtoken.